# Is there a way to communicate data between computers without while loops? C++

Tags: c++, boost, streaming, live-streaming

I have been struggling to try and find my answer for this on google, as I dont know the exact terms I am looking to search for.

If someone were to build an msn messenger-like program, is it possible to have always-open connections and no while(true) loop? If so, could someone point me in the direction of how this is achieved?

Comment: You could sleep for a few ms, then when you come back see if there's a response.

Comment: Look for events and callbacks.

Comment: you could use for loops instead.

Comment: I think the concept you are looking for is reactive programming. I'm not familiar with any C++ implementations of it, but hopefully that helps.

Comment: There's going to be at least _one_ big loop somewhere. Without a loop, things can only happen once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `boost::asio` library for socket handling, i think it is possible to define callbacks upon data reception.

Answer (score 3):

The one single magic word your looking for is *asynchronous I/O*. This can be achieved either through using asynchronous APIs (functions such as ReadThis() that return immediately and signal on success/failure -- like but not limited by boost::asio) or by deferring blocking calls to different threads. Picking either method requires careful weighing of both the underlying implementation and the scale of your operations.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [ACE](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html). It has a Reactor pattern which will notify you when data is available to be use.

[Reactor Pattern](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/PDF/reactor-siemens.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

You could have:

```
 while(1) {
    sleep(100); // 100 ms
    // check if there is a message
    // process message
    //...
 }
```

This is ok, but there is an overhead on servers running 10000s of threads since threads come out of sleep and check for a message, causing context-switching. Instead, operating systems provide functions like `select` and `epoll` on Linux, which allow a thread to wait on an event.

```
 while(1) {
    // wait for message
    // process message
    //...
 }
```

Using wait, the thread is not "woken up" unless a message is received.

Answer (score 0):

You can only hide your while loop (or some kind of loop) somewhere buried in some library or restart the waiting for next IO in an event callback, but you aren't going to be able to completely avoid it.

Comment: could you explain what you mean by 'restart the waiting for next IO in an event callback'?

Comment: Any IO blocks until some data is available then the data is handled in a callback, once the callback completes the blocking  continues which the callback itself may initiate or it can be in some type of loop. Non-blocking IO is a slightly different story though.

Answer (score 0):

That's a great question.  Like nj said, you want to use asynchronous I/O.  Too many programs use a polling strategy.  It is not uncommon to have 1000 threads running on a system.  If all of them were polling, you would have a slow system.  Use asynchronous I/O whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

what about udp protocol communication ? you dont have to wait in while loop for every clients 
 just open one connection on specified port and call receive method